# XSLT How to call other node by substring of current node name?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML document with belowe structure:

```
<Data>
   <FieldBook>
     <PointRecord>
       <Name>12_REF1</Name>
       (...)
     </PointRecord>
     <PointRecord>
       <Name>12_REF2</Name>
       (...)
     </PointRecord>
     <PointRecord>
       <Name>12</Name>
       (...)
     </PointRecord>
   </FieldBook>
   <Reductions>
    <Point>
        <Name>12_REF1</Name>
        <MyNecessaryValue>9999</MyNecessaryValue>
    </Point>
    <Point>
        <Name>12_REF2</Name>
        <MyNecessaryValue>8888</MyNecessaryValue>
    </Point>
    <Point>
        <Name>12</Name>
        <MyNecessaryValue>1000</MyNecessaryValue>
    </Point>
   </Reductions>
</Data>
```

Most of my data is located in *FieldBook*, but i have to also call some of *Reductions* nodes to get other data, generally looping through records using its IDs.

But, I have to also get specific values for calculations: eg. I have to compare  *MyNecessaryValue* of  *Reductions/Point* **12_REF1** and **12_REF2** both with *Reductions/Point* **12**, so I have to call the same node for two records in loop.

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63262675/xslt-how-to-call-xml-item-without-id-partameter/63263055#63263055) I prepared a key `<xsl:key name="red-pointName" match="Reductions/Point" use="Name"/>` and tried to use it this way, with substring:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/JOBFile/FieldBook/PointRecord">
   (...)    
     <td>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Method='GpsContinuousOffsetPointOne'">
                <xsl:call-template name="my-format">
                <xsl:with-param name="Val" select="key('red-pointName', substring-before-last(current(Name),'_')')/MyNecessaryValue"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="format" select="$DecPl2"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>---</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </td>
  (...) 
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it not works.

How can I call more than one time the same node?

Answer (score 0):

If you want e.g. `key('red-pointName', '12')` to find all `Point` elements where the `Name` starts with `12` before `_` then you need to change the key declaration to e.g. `<xsl:key name="red-pointName" match="Reductions/Point" use="replace(Name, '_.*$', '')"/>`. and of course make sure anywhere you call the `key` function you then ensure you only pass in the right value, i.e. the string before the `_`.

Comment: Thank you Martin! I have tried this, but software I use can't gerenate HTML output with your changes. Maybe there is something wrong with my input XML file or my implementation in xsl:with-param name="Val" select='...'. I will try to investigate this.